# Speed up reading gpkg as GeoPandas dataframe

Tags: python, geopandas, geopackage

I have multiple point gpkg files which I would like to use with GeoPandas, however, reading files into the script takes always very long when files are bigger > 150MB.

Generally I just read the data with:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(r'path/to/file.gpkg')
```

However, this is always pretty slow. Is there some other way to read the data, but still be able to work with dataframes?

Comment: 150MiB of points is an awful lot of points, so it would be expected to take some time. Since you haven't indicated the type of device on which the data is loaded (HDD/SSD), or the actual number of features, or even an exact time measurement for loading,  we have no way to tell if this is a problem.

Comment: 150MB is actually relatively good to handle dataset, it takes couple of minutes (probably 2min to read) . Maybe geopandas is not even the right way to process those data, but I may need to switch to a Geodatabase as Postgre with PostGIS. However, I thought I first ask if there is a trick on how to load those data faster and still being able to use methods of geopandas.

Comment: You're loading a ton of data from disk into RAM. That takes time. There's no reason to believe it would be faster from PostgreSQL (though it would cost hours/days to set that up and find out).

Comment: What would be a good choice then to process this kind of modest-sized geodata? I thought a postgreSQL setup with postGIS would do a good help. However, I think in the longer term I have to switch to something different (I think at using pyspark?).

Comment: You probably won't be able to speed up reading of the GeoPackage, but if another format would be an option, consider GeoParquet: https://cloudnativegeo.org/blog/2023/08/performance-explorations-of-geoparquet-and-duckdb/

Comment: Check the benchmarks in https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc86_column_oriented_api.html. There are differences in the speed between the formats, but the differences between the implementation are much bigger. Geopandas seems to be the slowest of all the tested methods (with geopackage 227 seconds vs 4.8 seconds for the fastest alternative).

Comment: I just made an interesting 'discovery': I have a shapefile of pointgeometries with a feature count of about 800 000. This shapefile has a size of 1.07GB. I then join a column with ids to it and save it as geopackage, and the exact same data inkl the new column now has a size of 141MB.However, if compare the reading time with geopandas it is about the same. So it seems while geopackages don't need as much space when stored, they need the same amount of time to  be processed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Install and use the optional [pyogrio](https://pyogrio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) I/O engine to read the data... that will be a lot faster. Adding the `use_arrow=True` parameter as well will give another big performance improvement, but then you'll also have to install the `pyarrow` library:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(r'path/to/file.gpkg', engine='pyogrio', use_arrow=True)
```

You can also change the defaults globally

- `geopandas.options.io_engine = "pyogrio"`
- `os.environ["PYOGRIO_USE_ARROW"] = 1`

Some timings using a 360 MB .gpkg with [polygon data](https://landbouwcijfers.vlaanderen.be/open-geodata-landbouwgebruikspercelen) (on windows):

```
read_file took 0:07:15.306107 with fiona engine (= the current default)
read_file took 0:00:24.831681 with pyogrio engine
read_file took 0:00:02.830280 with pyogrio engine and use_arrow=True
```

Comment: Confirmed by the benchmarks https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc86_column_oriented_api.html even your fiona timing is suspicious. How can it be so slow?

Comment: Ah, I think I installed pyogrio a week ago and there was an error so I didn't try further, but will retry it!

Comment: @user30184 What Pieter showed on how long it takes with Fiona engine corresponds exactly to my experience with reading gpkg with that size with the fiona engine. I don't know what it causes

Comment: @user30184 I know there is a big performance difference between windows and linux... and I'm working on windows.

Comment: Maybe it would be good to show the numbers for Fiona developers. Obviously Fiona is now handling gpkg/SQLite in some non-optimal way.

Comment: pyogrio started as a proof of concept that was discussed in a [fiona issue](https://github.com/Toblerity/Fiona/issues/469) and the decision was made to keep it separate because it would impact the API too much... So they are aware of the faster ways to deal with this. The next major version of geopandas will switch to using pyogrio by default...

Comment: I just used the pyogrio-engine with pyarrow as suggested from you, and wow, it is such a big diffference! This changes a lot for my daily work. Many thanks to @Pieter

Comment: For those who use ipython a lot (e.g. within Jupyter notebooks) and you don't want to import default libraries or set each time the option at the beginning of a script, you can set default libraries and options by creating a script `start.py` in the folder (on windows) `C:\Users\yourUsername\.ipython\profile_default\startup`. In the `script.py` you then just write `import geopandas as gpd` and `gpd.options.io_engine = "pyogrio"`, restart your ipython and from then per default you import geopandas and read your geofiles with pyogrio.